# How to extended the range variable with CurrentRegion property (vba)?

Tags: vba, range

The range variable extends with the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Function ESTENDISELEZIONE(Area As Range) As Range
    Set ESTENDISELEZIONE = Range(Area, Area.End(xlDown))
End Function
```

But it doesn't extends with:

```
Option Explicit
Function ESTENDISELEZIONE(Area As Range) As Range
    Set ESTENDISELEZIONE = Range(Area, Area.CurrentRegion)
End Function
```

And with:

```
Option Explicit
Function ESTENDISELEZIONE(Area As Range) As Range
    Set ESTENDISELEZIONE = Area.CurrentRegion
End Function
```

The procedure extends the range!

```
Sub EXTENDSELECTION()
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
End Sub
```

Can someone help me?

I've added an example to the question.

In the cell:

```
=CONTA.SE(ESTENDISELEZIONE(B2);"Orange")
```

In the formula:

```
Option Explicit
Function ESTENDISELEZIONE(Area As Range) As 
Range
    MsgBox(Area.Address)
    Set ESTENDISELEZIONE = Area.CurrentRegion
    MsgBox(ESTENDISELEZIONE.Address)
End Function
```

Comment: Would you specify what you mean by *"works"* and *"doesn't work"*?

Comment: I have just corrected the question. Thank you.

Comment: I tested the first method you say doesn't work, and it worked for me.  How are you using this code?  Maybe include into the question the parts of your other code that is calling the functions.

Comment: These is the my code. The first and fourth code works for me but not second and third. First and fourth i do not need them.

Comment: But how are you using this code?  Do you have another Sub with a line saying something like `Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ESTENDISELEZIONE(Range("A1"))`?

Comment: I do not need them sub but only function.

Comment: Well, if you aren't going to use this code anywhere, why worry whether it works or doesn't work?  And how do you know it's not working if you aren't using it?

Comment: All code is tested!

Comment: I'm not seeing the edited question (still says edited 23 minutes ago).  Have you pressed "Save Edits" yet?  (I often forget to do that myself.)  And, FWIW, the third method also works for me.

Comment: The range variable extends with the following code:.....First code......But it doesn't extends with:......Second code......And with:.....third code......The procedure extends the range!......Fouth code.

Comment: Functions 1, 2, 3 work for me.  The Sub just changes the `Selection` and, if that is all you intended it to do, that works for me too.  How are you calling the Functions?  It is almost certainly **that** code that is causing your problems.

Comment: The code ending correctly but. i explain:   the continuous range is B1:H4...... I selected B1 and with the second and third function above, the CurrentRegion remain B1 instead of extend it. With the fourth code (the procedure) it expands correctly in B1:H4. You understand?

Comment: So you're saying that you called the function using something like `rng = ESTENDISELEZIONE(Range("B1"))` and then `rng.Address` was still just `$B$1`?

Comment: Or are you trying to use this as a UDF?  i.e. you are entering a formula in Excel somewhere saying `=ESTENDISELEZIONE(B1)`?

Comment: "So you're saying that you called the function using something like rng = ESTENDISELEZIONE(Range("B1")) and then rng.Address was still just $B$1?"     Exactly.

Comment: "Or are you trying to use this as a UDF? i.e. you are entering a formula in Excel somewhere saying =ESTENDISELEZIONE(B1)? "  Exactly too.

Comment: OK - so we have determined that you have code calling this function.  Can you please include the full code that is calling the function into the question please.

Comment: I've upgrade the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CurrentRegion` property of a `Range` object won't work in a **UDF**.

And it doesn't make much sense to try, as it will cause untold problems.  Imagine that you changed cell C6 in your spreadsheet - the cell containing `=CONTA.SE(ESTENDISELEZIONE(B2);"Orange")` will not be recalculated (because it isn't dependent on cell C6) which means you start getting inconsistent data in your worksheet.

---

Note:  Your code works fine if just being used as a normal `Function`.  It is only when used as a UDF that it will have problems.

Comment: Thank you for your patient YowE3K. I understand your explanation. I agree. :-(